# How can I build a LINQ predicate/dynamic.LINQ query based off grid filtering when the grid properties don't have the entity properties?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq, predicatebuilder

I have a grid passing me filters. So I may have an object like:

```
var filter = new Filter(){
   Member = "Titles",
   Operator = Filter.Operators.IsEqualTo,
   Value = "Developer"
};
```

Then I need to take this and extend an IQueryable so to do that, I use dynamic.LINQ and have a method to apply these filters:

```
private IQueryable<TReportClass> ApplyFilter(ReportFilter filter, IQueryable<TReportClass> baseQuery)
    {
        switch (filter.Operator)
        {
            case ReportFilter.Operators.Contains:
                baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(string.Format("{0}.Contains(@0)", filter.Member), filter.Value);
                break;
            case ReportFilter.Operators.DoesNotContain:
                baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(string.Format("!{0}.Contains(@0)", filter.Member), filter.Value);
                break;
            case ReportFilter.Operators.IsEqualTo:
                baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(string.Format("{0} = @0", filter.Member), filter.Value);
                break;
            case ReportFilter.Operators.IsNotEqualTo:
                baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(string.Format("{0} != @0", filter.Member), filter.Value);
                break;
            case ReportFilter.Operators.StartsWith:
                baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(string.Format("{0}.StartsWith(@0)", filter.Member), filter.Value);
                break;
            case ReportFilter.Operators.EndsWith:
                baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(string.Format("{0}.EndsWith(@0)", filter.Member), filter.Value);
                break;
            case ReportFilter.Operators.IsNull:
                baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(string.Format("{0} = NULL", filter.Member));
                break;
            case ReportFilter.Operators.IsNotNull:
                baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(string.Format("{0} != NULL", filter.Member));
                break;
            case ReportFilter.Operators.IsEmpty:
                baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(string.Format("string.IsNullOrEmpty({0})", filter.Member));
                break;
            case ReportFilter.Operators.IsNotEmpty:
                baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(string.Format("!string.IsNullOrEmpty({0})", filter.Member));
                break;
        }

        return baseQuery;
    }
```

However this works only for non-collections. How can I get it to work with collections? If I have this model:

```
public class UserReport : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<string> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

And this query as a base:

```
IQueryable<UserReport> baseQuery = MyDbContext.DbSet<User>.Select(user => new UserReport
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
            Email = user.Email,
            Titles = user.Positions.Select(apptment => apptment.Title).ToList()
        })
```

So I can call like:

```
IQueryable<UserReport> filteredQuery = ApplyFilters(filters, baseQuery);
```

How do I transform the above filter to translate into a LINQ like:

```
baseQuery.Where(userReport => userReport.Titles.Any(title => title == "Developer")
```

Can that be done with dynamic LINQ? Or do I need to build my own predicate? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with both `System.Linq.Dynamic` and `System.Linq.Expressions`.

Here is the solution with `System.Linq.Dynamic` to keep it close to your current code. All you need is to identify if the member is collection and use the following pattern for the dynamic criteria:

*Collection:*  `{PropertyName}.Any(it{condition})`
*Object:*      `{PropertyName}{condition}`

And the implementation could be like this (basically replacing `string.Format` with `Func<string, string, string>`):

```
private IQueryable<TReportClass> ApplyFilter(ReportFilter filter, IQueryable<TReportClass> baseQuery)
{
    var property = typeof(TReportClass).GetProperty(filterMember);
    bool isCollection = property.Type != typeof(string) &&
        && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.Type);
    Func<string, string, string> condtion;
    if (isCollection)
        condition = (format, member) => string.Format("{0}.Any({1})", member, string.Format(format, "it"));
    else
        condition = (format, member) => string.Format(format, member);
    switch (filter.Operator)
    {
        case ReportFilter.Operators.Contains:
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(condition("{0}.Contains(@0)", filter.Member), filter.Value);
            break;
        case ReportFilter.Operators.DoesNotContain:
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(condition("!{0}.Contains(@0)", filter.Member), filter.Value);
            break;
        case ReportFilter.Operators.IsEqualTo:
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(condition("{0} = @0", filter.Member), filter.Value);
            break;
        case ReportFilter.Operators.IsNotEqualTo:
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(condition("{0} != @0", filter.Member), filter.Value);
            break;
        case ReportFilter.Operators.StartsWith:
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(condition("{0}.StartsWith(@0)", filter.Member), filter.Value);
            break;
        case ReportFilter.Operators.EndsWith:
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(condition("{0}.EndsWith(@0)", filter.Member), filter.Value);
            break;
        case ReportFilter.Operators.IsNull:
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(condition("{0} = NULL", filter.Member));
            break;
        case ReportFilter.Operators.IsNotNull:
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(condition("{0} != NULL", filter.Member));
            break;
        case ReportFilter.Operators.IsEmpty:
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(condition("string.IsNullOrEmpty({0})", filter.Member));
            break;
        case ReportFilter.Operators.IsNotEmpty:
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(condition("!string.IsNullOrEmpty({0})", filter.Member));
            break;
    }

    return baseQuery;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, would it be more performant to only use reflection once outside of ApplyFilter and pass ApplyFilter all the collection property names instead of using reflection on each ApplyFilter call? Also I am curious as to why the reflection is first checking if property is not of `typeof(string)` and it's assignable from `typeof(IEnumerable)`? Couldn't I just have one statement that checks if `typeof(IEnumerable<string>).IsAssignableFrom(property.Type)` ?

Comment: (1) In this case the affect of reflection is negligible. It's not something that is executed per each element of the result set. Also building expressions trees with `System.Linq.Expressions` classes does a lot of reflection anyway - how do you think Dynamic LINQ processes the passed string. (2) If you support only `string` lists, it will be sufficient. The above is more general and works for any list with values. Of course some of your filter operators are defined only for strings, but others like `Is(Not)EqualTo`, `Is(Not)Null` can be used for `int`s, `DateTime`s etc.

Comment: Anyway, the above is just a sample implementation, you could adjust it for your needs :)

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that, interesting. Good point about other types, I hadn't even considered that. All these filters logic only work if the column is of type string then right? I do use some ints, bools, and Datetimes in my grids as well. I couldn't apply something like Contains to a bool. However, I think my grid filters automatically know that, It would never try and pass a filter for a bool where the operator was set to contains.

Comment: It depends what the `filter.Value` contains. If it's a string, then yes, the filters would work only for string properties. But they can be made to work with other types by using `var value = Convert.ChangeType(filter.Value, property.Type)` for instance.